# Instalação do babel-cli e live-server localmente

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babel

Estou instalando o babel-cli e live-server localmente, porém, ele está dando um problema dizendo que:

```
run `npm audit fix` to fix 3 of them.
1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Quando escrevo npm audit, ele aparece isto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema que me causa é porque quando eu entrar no package.json era pra estar nas depedencies o babel-cli e o live-server, e não está, clico para salvar o arquivo, e ele fala para comparar o arquivo que era pra estar. Vejo a comparação e da pra ser visto que tem as dependencies que eu queria, tento fazer manualmente e não tem como.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Na esquerda onde tem as linhas vermelhas seria o arquivo que era pra ser, e ao lado direito, o meu arquivo atual.**

Comment: Utilize a versão mais recente das dependências. Motivo: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualizando!
Eu desinstal o babel-cli e o live-server usando o comando:

```
npm uninstall babel-cli live-server
```

E ao instalar novamente usei o comando de instalação juntamente com a flag --save-dev, ficando assim:

```
npm install babel-cli@6.26.0 live-server@1.2.0 --save-dev
```

Conseguindo por fim instalar no package.json ficando assim com as dependencies e devDependencies
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]